# Flask application on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask, port

I have uploaded a flask project on a ec2 instance and run it with this command:

```
python app.py
```

And the server give me this information:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
```

Everything seems to be okay, but I cant get connection to the webpage..
I have also opened all TCP ports on the server

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this question. If you make a [small, trival edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270383/1086529), I can undo the downvote and delete this comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your flask app listen on all IPs by passing a parameter in `app.run()`

`app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`

[View QuickStart documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/)